# Do I have to use "I" or "we" when orally presenting my scientific thesis written by a single author?

Tags: speech, academia, register, scientific-language

I know that in a scientific paper or thesis made by a single author, it is common to use *we*. (This is also recommended at our university.)

But what about when you alone are **presenting** a thesis work orally?

At first glance, it is quite odd to use *we* when the work is written only by you yourself and you are presenting it alone.

For example, saying:

> **We** will present you **my** machine learning model...

while at the same time you stand alone in front of the examiners seems very strange to me.

Is this style of presentation expected, tolerated, or forbidden?

Comment: If there's only one of you on stage, I would find "We will present..." a little odd but whether it's "my machine learning model..." or "our machine learning model..." will depend on who is being represented.

Comment: Is it the product of a single researcher or a group?

Comment: I'd say it depends on how many authors there are. "We" if there are multiple, even if you are presenting on your own. Alternatively it can be "I'll now present OUR machine learning model" to point out that you are presenting results of a group.

Comment: I used “I” in my Oxford D Phil thesis, and that was 50 years ago! When you write “it is recommended”, you are avoiding telling us who advocated this antiquated convention. More to the point, you present your model *to* someone, and in English-speaking countries they are examiners, not a jury.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Maybe I was a little bit unclear here, but this work is made by a single author (me). I adapted the question.

Comment: Note that you may get a more suitable audience for your question on [academia.se]. Just make sure to distinguish it from [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2945/7734).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

> **We** will be presenting **my** machine learning model,

is completely wrong. When you are writing a thesis, you would use **we** instead of **I** and **our** instead of **my**. The **we** combined with the **my** doesn't work. Similarly, this combination doesn't work when giving an single-presenter oral presentation. It implies that several people are speaking, but somehow that only one person came up with the machine learning model.

In an oral presentation, you should use **I** when you want to refer to yourself as the person giving the presentation. For your work, you can either use **I/me/my** or **we/us/our**. If it was joint work with somebody else, definitely use **we/us/our**. If it's your own single-authored work, I think using **I/me/my** is more common, but I don't think anything is wrong with using the scientific **we/us/our**.

So in an oral presentation, you should say one of:

> **I** will be presenting **my** machine learning model,
>   **I** will be presenting **our** machine learning model.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting up on the rule that, traditionally, scientific theses were *written* in the *passive voice* and avoided any kind of personal pronoun.

For example:

> *The* results of experiment X are compared to the results from experiment Y.

***Not*** "*I compared the results from experiment X.....*"

Apparently though, thoughts on this have changed in more recent times and it is more common to use personal pronouns in research writing.

[This article](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/personal-pronouns/) by Professor of Statistics and Head of the Department of Econometrics and Business Statistics at Monash University Rob J Hyndman suggests:

- Write in the most natural way. It is ok if that means using “I”.
- Use “we” if you mean “the reader and I”, or if you are writing a co-authored paper.
- Don’t use “we” if you only mean yourself.

Not only does it seems logical that you would use the same approach when *presenting* a thesis as when writing it, but it would also be very odd to present something orally in the passive voice. At the very least it would be very dry and un-engaging.

Comment: Has there ever been a time when oral scientific presentations (which is what the OP is asking about) were delivered in the passive voice?

Comment: @PeterShor No, good point - I got a bit lost making my point halfway through. I have edited to try and make that stand out.

Comment: Using passive voice is an option, thank you for your suggestion. Although it sounds "boring" to me to use it constantly. Also, it is not recommended by my university to use passive voice for the same reason, but that applies only when writing a thesis, for a presentation, no guidelines were given. If I understand correctly, you advise in this situation to use "I" since this is a product of one author?